# Keep a connection to a third party service open across requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety, singleton

I have this module that works as an adaptor for a 3rd party service:

```
module Salesforce
  class ConnectionService
    class << self
      def client
        @client ||= Restforce.new(
          # Connection Params
        )
      end 

      delegate :query, :create!, :update!, :upsert!, to: :client
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is to call it as:

```
Salesforce::ConnectionService.query('select things from remote service')
```

My goal is that, because establishing the connection takes some time, I would like to be able to memoize it to recycle it across requests.

The problem is that having instance variables in class methods seems not to be thread-safe. So I would like to know what would be the proper way to do it.

Note: I know that for now, I am not taking into account the case when the connection closes, I will deal with it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to refactor using one of the many configuration patterns which memoizes the instance. But you can take a quick-and-dirty workaround:

`config/application.rb`:

```
module DanielApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    def salesforce_client
      @salesforce_client ||= Restforce.new(host: 'test.salesforce.com')
    end 
  end
end
```

then,

```
Rails.application.salesforce_client.query("select Id, Something__c from Account where Id = 'someid'")
```

Or you could define some sort of global in an initializer and then call it from there.

Comment: It makes sense. But does it have any advantage concerning my initial approach? Would this `salesforce_client` be thread-safe?

Comment: @Daniel why do you think it's not threadsafe? Can it not handle multiple requests simultaneously? That being said, you can use a mutex to synchronize your threads ... see [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Mutex.html)